# Git Hook - Ruby Code - Interactive Input

Tags: ruby, git, githooks, popen3, ruby-thread

I am trying to take input from git hook execution code(commit-msg hook). But the ruby is not able to stop at the input point. And its executing the code as if input is like a puts statement. Here is the code I tried and failed.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'open3'

def take_input_here

  Open3.popen3("pwd", :chdir=>"/") {|stdin, stdout, stderr, thread|
    p stdout.read.chomp #=> "/"
  }

  input_val = gets.chomp
  puts input_val
  puts 'Hellow World!'
end
take_input_here
puts "Commit Aborted."
Process.exit(1)
```

Somebody please help my take this interactive input or else suggest me a good language for writing git hooks. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Most Git hooks are run with stdin either coming from a pipe to which Git writes information, or with stdin disconnected from the terminal entirely.  The `commit-msg` hook falls into this second category.

It won't matter which language you use: reading stdin in a `commit-msg` hook will see EOF immediately, as stdin is connected to `/dev/null` (Linux/Unix) or `NUL:` (Windows).

On Unix-like systems, you can try opening `/dev/tty`.  Note that if Git is being run from something that doesn't *have* a `/dev/tty` (some detached process, e.g., via `cron`) or where reading `/dev/tty` is bad for some other reason, this may cause other issues, so be careful with this.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I do have to search another way then. :)